# Is entropy a good indicator of the quality of a lossy compression?

Tags: algorithms, information-theory, data-compression, entropy, philosophy

Say I want to quantitively evaluate the effectiveness of several color-to-grayscale conversion algorithms, which can be considered as lossy compression. Would entropy be a good indicator?

To calculate the entropy of a file, I first convert it to a byte stream with `hexdump(1)` or some other methods (see below). Next, this stream of bytes is considered as a Markov chain, and its transition matrix is estimated by examining consecutive bytes, [from which entropy is calculated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040972/entropy-of-a-markov-chain-right-result). The stationary distribution can be estimated by counting all bytes in the file if needed.

There are three caveats, however:

1. Sometimes you need to use longer "byte"s. For example, if the file is encoded with UTF-16, then an atomic unit should contain exactly 16 bits. Fortunately, almost all pictures use True color (24-bit), or 8-bit or RGB respectively, so this won't be a big problem.
2. Pictures are inherently 2D structures, and `hexdump` basically coerces them to 1D linear structures, but that's inappropriate. The file should be traversed in another way so that the positional change is as smooth as possible, like

```
* > *   * > *               * > * > * > *
  /   /   /                  /----<----/
*   *   *   *               * > * > * > *
| /   /   / |    <- GOOD     /----<----/     <- BAD
*   *   *   *               * > * > * > *
  /   /   /                  /----<----/
* > *   * > *               * > * > * > *
```

3. The input and output of algorithms to be compared against each other must be the same.

Any thought is appreciated!

Comment: Please define *quality* and/or *effectiveness* of a data conversion. (*Effective*? Colour before, greyscale after: 100% effective. But *data reduction* rather than *compression*: good luck with trying to decompress/recreating something resembling the original) I can't see a difference in "smooth"ness between *GOOD* and *BAD*. There are quit a number of [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), Hilbert the one coming to my mind first.

Comment: @greybeard Actually the definition is what I'm asking in the question! Vaguely speaking, I want to quantify the loss of information in a sensible way, but I have no idea which property to focus on. GOOD is more smooth because the positional difference of two consecutive points is at most two (move up/down one pixel, then move left/right on pixel), whereas BAD forces the sampler to go all the way left to the beginning of the next line. I suppose the smoother the better, because pixels on a picture generally have space continuousness. The Hilbert curve seems even better than GOOD, by the way!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_quality

Comment: (I mis"read" your *BAD* sketch, seeing horizontal scans alternating in direction. I can see *worse*, now.)

Comment: What exactly is the definition of "effectiveness"?  That sounds subjective.  What is or isn't a good indicator sounds like a matter of opinion, too, if effectiveness is not clearly defined in the question.  Those kinds of questions aren't a good fit here; we're looking for questions that can be objectively answered.  If you're asking how to quantify effectiveness, you'll probably need to first figure out what exactly you mean by that effectiveness.

Comment: @D.W. Yeah, I understand... I'm just hoping someone appear and define effectiveness for an image. I mean, before Shannon, "information" was a subject matter either, but he defined information entropy in an objective fashion.